# copyFromLocal Hadoop No such file or directory error

Tags: fedora, hadoop

I have the following code from the Fedora command terminal :

```
[root@localhost python_code]# pwd
/root/python_code
[root@localhost python_code]# cd ..
[root@localhost ~]# ls
anaconda-ks.cfg  python_code
[root@localhost ~]# cd /usr/local
[root@localhost local]# ls
bin  games   hadoop-2.6.4.tar.gz  input        lib    libexec  sbin   src
etc  hadoop  include              jdk1.8.0_77  lib64  output   share
[root@localhost local]# cd hadoop
[root@localhost hadoop]# ls
bin  include  libexec      logs        README.txt  share
etc  lib      LICENSE.txt  NOTICE.txt  sbin
[root@localhost hadoop]# pwd
/usr/local/hadoop
[root@localhost hadoop]# bin/hdfs dfs -copyFromLocal /root/python_code/input_data.csv /usr/local/hadoop/input_localuser
copyFromLocal: `/usr/local/hadoop/input_localuser': No such file or directory
[root@localhost hadoop]# ls
bin  include  libexec      logs        README.txt  share
etc  lib      LICENSE.txt  NOTICE.txt  sbin
[root@localhost hadoop]# mkdir input_localuser
[root@localhost hadoop]# ls
bin  include          lib      LICENSE.txt  NOTICE.txt  sbin
etc  input_localuser  libexec  logs         README.txt  share
[root@localhost hadoop]# bin/hdfs dfs -copyFromLocal /root/python_code/input_data.csv /usr/local/hadoop/input_localuser
copyFromLocal: `/usr/local/hadoop/input_localuser': No such file or directory
[root@localhost hadoop]# bin/hdfs dfs -copyFromLocal /root/python_code/input_data.csv home/usr/local/hadoop/input_localuser
copyFromLocal: `home/usr/local/hadoop/input_localuser': No such file or directory
[root@localhost hadoop]# pwd
/usr/local/hadoop
[root@localhost hadoop]# ls
bin  include          lib      LICENSE.txt  NOTICE.txt  sbin
etc  input_localuser  libexec  logs         README.txt  share
[root@localhost hadoop]#
```

More Code :

```
[root@localhost hadoop]# cd ~
[root@localhost ~]# ls
anaconda-ks.cfg  python_code
[root@localhost ~]# cd python_code
[root@localhost python_code]# ls
data_generator.py  input_data.csv  mapper_project.py  reducer_project.py
[root@localhost python_code]#
```

As seen above, my `python_code` directory is in root folder and I am trying to copy files from that folder to the directory `input_userlocal` which is inside hadoop.

But the following command is throwing an error:

```
bin/hdfs dfs -copyFromLocal /root/python_code/input_data.csv /usr/local/hadoop/input_localuser
    copyFromLocal: `/usr/local/hadoop/input_localuser': No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, your Hadoop command is likely incorrect.

`dfs -copyFromLocal` expects two parameters, a local file (as you have specified) and then an Hadoop URI.  Not as you have given it, a file path.

From the Hadoop web pages,

> All FS shell commands take path URIs as arguments. The URI format is
>   scheme://authority/path. For HDFS the scheme is hdfs, and for the
>   Local FS the scheme is file. The scheme and authority are optional. If
>   not specified, the default scheme specified in the configuration is
>   used. An HDFS file or directory such as /parent/child can be specified
>   as hdfs://namenodehost/parent/child or simply as /parent/child (given
>   that your configuration is set to point to hdfs://namenodehost).
>
> Most of the commands in FS shell behave like corresponding Unix
>   commands. Differences are described with each of the commands. Error
>   information is sent to stderr and the output is sent to stdout.

I don't know the structure of your Hadoop instance, but your target needs to be a name based on that, not simply the filesystem.

Secondly, you don't show us above the contents of `/root/python_code/`, are you sure `input_data.csv` exists?

Comment: I have updated the code with above contents of `/root/python_code` and the file exists. And `http://localhost:50070/dfshealth.html#tab-overview` shows a web page on my browser.

Comment: And what's the Hadoop URI that specifies the target?  It's not `/usr/local/hadoop/input_localuser`

Comment: How do I find that URI using web page?

Comment: I've no clue - you built the hadoop cluster so you really need to understand how to refer to it using URIs.  I recommend you go back to the hadoop manual and work it out?

Comment: Okay, let me check that.